# How to make a slideshow with multiple images in 1 slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i want to make a slideshow in my feature products section by adding arrows at the sides. I intend to make it so that when the user clicks on the arrow it shows the next 3 featured products.
How do I do that? I want the next slide to be the exact same as the first slide with 3 featured products. [My featured products section i want arrows on the left and right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evcNm.png)

Comment: Maybe you should simply use a framework like https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ . The code for a slideshow framework goes from simple to much more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use slick carousel plugin :  http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/